# Airflow PyTest DagBag Import Error from local module

Tags: python, airflow, pytest

I have a directory structure as follows for my DAGs:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── _base.py
├── dag1.py
├── dag2.py
├── dag3.py
├── ...
```

When I run PyTest to fill my DagBag, I get the following error for each DAG file

```
ERROR - Failed to import: dags/dag2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/code/myproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 339, in parse
    loader.exec_module(new_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "dags/dag2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _base import start_here, task_factory
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_base'
```

My _base.py is a helper file that holds common task declarations like:

```
def task_factory(
    operator_func,
    base_env_vars=[],
    op_kwargs={},
):
    def build_airflow_task(task_id=None, extra_env_vars=[], **kwargs):
        task = operator_func(
            task_id=task_id,
            name=task_id,
            env_vars=[*base_env_vars, *extra_env_vars],
            **op_kwargs,
            **kwargs,
        )
        return task

    return build_airflow_task
```

In each DAG file, I do the following:

```
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.kubernetes_engine import (
    GKEStartPodOperator,
)
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

from _base import start_here, finish, dummy_task, task_factory
```

I am not sure how to instrument Airflow/PyTest to find _base.py for tests, but in my actual deployment (Google Cloud Composer), my DAG files are able to find and import from `_base.py` without issue.

My test file looks like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "..")

from airflow.models import DagBag


def test_dagbag_compiles():
    dags = DagBag("dags", include_examples=False)
    assert len(dags.import_errors) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is adding your module to python path:

```bash
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/module pytest ...
```